# Getting a Google Spreadsheet Cell's Image URL

Tags: image, url, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that has an image on the 2nd and 3rd column of each row, and I am trying to log all of the spreadsheet data to the console (for now).  I'm having trouble accessing the image within each cell because the `getValue()` function will not return the source url for the image.  All of the images were inserted into the spreadsheet using `=image("http://imagesource.com",3)`.  Here is what I have so far, edited from the default readRows function Google provides:

```
  function readRows() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var numCols = rows.getNumColumns();

    for (var i = 2; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
        // columns 2 and 3 always contain images  
        if (j == 2 || j == 3) {
          // gets the google spreadsheet url, not the original source url
          // of the image contained in the cell like I want it to
          var imgUrl = rows.getCell(i, j).getDataSourceUrl(); 
          Logger.log("[img]" + imgUrl + "[/img]");
        } else {
          var cellData = rows.getCell(i, j).getValue();
          Logger.log(cellData);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**: Looks like I can use `getFormula()` to return a String that looks like `=image("http://imagesource.com",3)` but that still leaves me with the issue of manipulating the string to include just the URL.  I'm not sure that's possible because strings look like they are a primitive data type in google scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range.getValue()` returns the computed value of a cell, which in this case is an image, not a URL. As you've found, you can use `getFormula()` to get the formula that created the image. You can use a regular expression to extract the image URL from the formula string.

```
function getImageUrl(formula) {
  var regex = /=image\("(.*)"/i;
  var matches = formula.match(regex);
  return matches ? matches[1] : null;
}
```

This won't work if the URL is computed from another cell or formula, but it should work for the simple case you have listed.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you!  I haven't worked with regular expressions before, so I will take a look at their uses so I can solve similar problems in the future.