# Get URL from image via script on Google Sheets - does this code still work?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using Google Sheets.

Cell A1:

```
=image("address.jpg")
```

This puts the image in a cell. To get the url from Stack Overflow produced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750321/getting-a-google-spreadsheet-cells-image-url).

I created the script, and Google recognised it in autocomplete. The error I am getting is:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "match" of null. (line 10).

I ran the regex through a checker, and it does get what I am looking for i.e the address, but the error seems to indicate that it's coming back with nothing.

Does this still work? Has Google changed something?

My work-around is to create two sheets and have §=image in one sheet, while in the second sheet, I remove § and use a standard Google function.

The linked solution is far better, and I'd like to implement that if I could. I cannot post a comment on the original solution's page as I don't have reputation points.

Comment: Can you provide more information of your situation? 1. From ``TypeError: Cannot call method "match" of null. (line 10).``, I cannot understand about your current script. 2. How did you run the script? 3. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? I think that such information will help users think of your solution.

Comment: @tanaike I copied the first accepted solution(Eric's) on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750321/getting-a-google-spreadsheet-cells-image-url, and created a new script called getImageURL. I also abided his caveat that 'This won't work if the URL is computed from another cell or formula' Line 10 is 'var matches = formula.match(regex);'

To reproduce: type =image("any url.jpg") into cell A1 in Google Sheets.
In cell B1, I type =getImageUrl(A1). 
And I get the null error, which seems to indicate Regex is wrong?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I modified the script for your situation. This is a simple modification. But if this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, "null" is given as an argument. Because the formula cannot be directly retrieved by `=getImageUrl(A1)`. By this, the error of `Cannot call method "match" of null.` occurs. The formula can be retrieved by `getFormula()`. This is also mentioned at Eric Koleda's answer. So for example, the script can be modified as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function getImageUrl(range) {
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getFormula(); // Added
  var regex = /=image\("(.*)"/i;
  var matches = formula.match(regex);
  return matches ? matches[1] : null;
}
```

#### Note:

- If `=image("URL")` is put in "A1", when you use this like `=getImageUrl("A1")`. **Please enclose A1 by the double quotes.** By this, the string of "A1" is given to the function and is used as the range.

#### Reference:

- [getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula)