# Display png thumbnail image from URL permanently in Google sheets cell

Tags: google-sheets, thumbnails

When you hoover over a URL ink in a cell in Google Sheets you get a thumbnail from the site. I am interested in having this png thumbnail permanently displayed in a cell. I can do this by going to the site, grabbing an image, and inserting it into the cell but this is a bit of a pain. Google sheets seems to have a way of grabbing a representative png from a website. Is there a way I can display the same png image that Google Sheets uses for a hover over thumbnail permanently in a cell? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to check this [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/129384672) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047414/image-as-cell-note-in-google-sheets-to-be-displayed-at-mouseover-hover?rq=1) seems to be related to your question