# using apps script, how to return image url

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheet, I'm using dropdown menu Insert -> Image -> Insert Image in Cell ,
using apps script, i want it to return  -
my code showing "CellImage" word instead of image url
my code :

```
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/MY_SHEET_ID/edit#gid=0").getSheetByName('Sheet1');

var range = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
var values = range.getValues();

Logger.log(values);
```

I tried using `getValues()` but I got "***CellImage***" word instead of an image url.

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56733340

Comment: You can use the hyperlink tag with a range.setFormula() method

Answer (score 0):

Hy Abby Adamina

Please check out: [Getting a Google Spreadsheet Cell's Image URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750321/getting-a-google-spreadsheet-cells-image-url)

***[Possible Duplicate]***